# items in notification area not coming up after startup

Tags: 10.04, startup, network-manager

My 3 year old played with my computer and now all items in the notification area are not coming up anymore, including

- nm-applet
- skype
- keyring

I have checked various sources on the Internet in regards to the problem, largely relating to nm-applet not being visible or keyring not starting. I was also able to restore .gconf/ and .gconfd from backup, but none of these helped.

I have checked that

- nm-applet --sm-disable
- /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11

are in my startup programs.

Where else can I look? Is there a log that I could check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restored from backup, which makes any answers somewhat obsolete

Answer (score 2):

Is the notification area added to the panel? If it isn't you can add it again by right clicking the panel, choosing add to panel, and drag and dropping the applet to the panel.

Comment: Yes, its there: About: Notification Area 2.30.2

Comment: @jdog wow... I am lost for a solution. You're 3yr old rocks then :D

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the notification area is there in the panel. May be the 3year old smart removed that by right clicking and remove or something like that. Just add that to panel.

Comment: @roland taylor just suggested that before. Right clicking on the 2 dotted lines shows "About->Notification Area 2.30.2". Is this the notification area that you mean or are we talking across purposes?